# Lotus View and Date values in column formula

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus, lotus-formula

Hi(sorry for possible dublicate).

I am trying to fix the performance issues in some of the legacy commercial databases which were badly designed in the past.

There are a lot of views in this databases and they are all containing the formulas **@Now, @Today** values in the view columns in the inner formulas, which are increasing Lotus Views open/refresh speed (as a notice, there is no dates manipulations in the view main selection formulas).

Information in this databases must to be always up to date and refreshed, so the solution with changing the view options (refresh time interval) are not good enough.

I am trying to create a global document (or to find similar solution), which will be updated one time at night with the server agent and will contains fields with year,month and day and trying to add this document as a subform to every document, so this fields with year e.t.c will be accessible in every document and so I could call them in my future column @-formulas and every day this field in this subform will be updated.

**Is it really possible/right solution? How can I do that? 
Can you please give some advice what is the best way to solve this?**

p.s. I have already read a ton of articles about Lotus Views performance issues when using dates and mostly all of them are about creating a server agent, which will update the selection formulas one time per day... but in my variant - I am having a formulas in the columns.

Thank you.

**UPDATED 03.03.2018:**

[Thanks to Knut Herrmann](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49070545/5331196), I have understood that I need to use an agent to update column formulas and that this is possible.
But I am also trying to understand why the view will work faster after the view formula will be updated? Not quite understand this solution.
Why it has no need to update view index every time after one-time formula is updated at the night and why it's refreshing every time now when I am not using this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the agent approach.

Change the column formula with [NotesViewColumn's Formula](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_FORMULA_PROPERTY.html) property every night:

```
Dim column as NotesViewColumn
set column = ...
column.Formula = "your column formula"
```

The idea behind the agent is to avoid `@Today` in column formulas as this function causes the view to refresh every time it is called.

*Example:*

Every night at 2 a.m. change column formula (to show the number of days left)

```
(@Date(Deadline) - @Today) / 86400
```

to

```
(@Date(Deadline) - @Date(2018; 03; 04)) / 86400
```

This way you eliminate the "dangerous" function "@Today" by replacing it with the current date in formula.

Comment: Thank you Knut Herrmann for your response! Do I need to configurate some specific view options after the columns formulas will be updated?  I am not quite understand why after the formula update - view will work faster e.t.c Can you please provide more information about this. Thank you.

Comment: I have updated my question, can you please provide more details, very interesting approach.

Comment: I added an example. Hope it makes the approach better understandable.

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to add a field to all the documents using the NotesDocumentCollection StampAll() method in a scheduled agent.  For example:

```
    dim db as NotesDatabase
    dim dc as NotesDocumentCollection
    dim todayDate as new NotesDateTime("")
    set dc = db.alldocuments() ' Or whatever selection of documents you want.
    set todayDate.localtime = format(Now(),"mm/dd/yyyy")
    call dc.stampall("TodayDate",todayDate)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have already tryed this variant. For this solution - all forms must to have a field todayDate. But in my case - I can't change forms. Knut's solution is more lightweigh and flexible for my situation, I think.

Comment: No, the form doesn't have to have that field, the document can have the field without it existing on the form.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thank you for this information.